# problemas al recorrer un array en php

Tags: php, mysql, array, php7, backend

Tengo un problema al recorrer el siguiente array, ya que el mismo no me recorre como debería ser. Pero cuando cambio $value['isbn'] = $value2['isbn'] si lo recorre pero entiendo que no esta bien por que se estaría asignando el valor de $value2['isbn] a $value['isbn'].

Y otra consulta como puedo ampliar el tiempo de consultas a una base de datos.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(1800);
$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=137.184.146.3;dbname=Libros','libros', 'Rodri2021');
$connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$F = $connect->prepare('select isbn from items');   
$F->execute();

$connect2 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=original','root', '');
$connect2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$F2 = $connect2->prepare('select * from sbs_import where MLC LIKE "%MLC%"');    
$F2->execute();
    
foreach ($F as  $value) {
  foreach ($F2 as $value2) {    
   if ($value['isbn'] == $value2['isbn']) {
   $F3 = $connect->prepare('UPDATE items set MLC = :X where isbn = :Y');    
   error_reporting($F3->execute(array('X' => $value2['MLC'], 'Y'=> $value['isbn'])));
   echo '<br>'.$value['isbn'].'<br>';
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Podrías poner  el arreglo ?

Comment: $value['isbn'] = $value2['isbn']

Comment: Es lo que esta dentro del condicional

Comment: @RodrigoEspinosa No, == es correcto.  Lo que dijo es asignación (y por eso siempre regresa true.)  Son actualmente iguales, $value y $value2, incluyendo espacios y puntos y eso?

Comment: Creo que estás ejecutando mal tu consulta al principio. Nunca capturas los datos, o los extraes luego de ejecutarla. Debes usar fetch o fetchAll. Cuando haces esa asignación es true porque ambos índices de tu array son iguales.

Answer (score 0):

Y si guardas el resultado de la consulta en un array tipo `$resultF = $F->fetchAll()`, y recorres el array con `$resultF` lo mismo para `$F2`